# How to calculate bearings between two points (in decimal degrees) using Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Having problems formulating the bearing from two points in decimal degrees in excel.  I'm using the following formula:

```
=MOD(ATAN2(SIN(LonB-LonA)*COS(LatB),COS(LatA*SIN(LatB)-SIN(LatA)*COS(LonB-LonA))),6.30318)
```

Example data

- Lat A (38.6318909290283)
- Lon A (-90.2828979492187)
- Lat B (38.5352759115441)
- Lon B(-89.8448181152343)

The answer I get is 5.024 degrees it should be 105.619 degrees

Comment: I don't know if the formula is correct or not, but Excel's `SIN` and `COS` function expect the angles in Radians, not Degrees

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you mistyped the formula when entering into excel.

Also, you need to convert degrees to radians, because excel takes input for trigonometric functions as radians. At the end, need to convert the result of ATAN2 back to degrees.
Solution:

```
=DEGREES(ATAN2(COS(RADIANS(latA))*SIN(RADIANS(latB))-SIN(RADIANS(latA))*COS(RADIANS(latB))*COS(RADIANS(lonB-lonA)),SIN(RADIANS(lonB-lonA))*COS(RADIANS(latB))))
```

Source for formula: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Comment: Jolly Thank you. I should have known that. Works and if I add =MOD(<expression>,360) I get the degrees from North.

Comment: that's right, glad I could help

Answer (score 2):

Calculating Azimuth referenced to North (0 degrees) between two x,y locations using UTM Easting and Northing coordinates in metres, I use the following formula:
Azimuth=
`=IF(AND(x>=0,y>=0),90-MOD(360+DEGREES(ATAN2(x,y)),360),450-MOD(360+DEGREES(ATAN2(x,y)),360))`

Cell name 'x' = distance (difference) between eastings in metres (target minus source)
Cell name 'y' = distance (difference) between northings in metres (target minus source)